# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') error but no values in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, knn

I am working on the Titanic machine problem from Kaggle - the beginner one.

I am writing my code in python, and the model type is K-NN.

I am receiving the error 'Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')', however, I have checked my data thoroughly. There are no infinite values, no NaN values, and no large values. The error is not thrown on my training set but is thrown on the test set - they are not different in values(Obviously different in content, but the type of value is same).
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_dataset = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
X_classt = test_dataset.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape((1,-1))
X_faret = test_dataset.iloc[:,8].values.reshape((1,-1))

X_Stpt = test_dataset.iloc[:,3:7]
X_embarkedt = test_dataset.iloc[:,10].values.reshape((-1,1))


X_onet = np.concatenate((X_classt,X_faret))
X_onet = np.matrix.transpose(X_onet)
X_twot = np.concatenate((X_Stpt,X_embarkedt),axis=1)

Xt = np.concatenate((X_onet,X_twot),axis=1)


from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN',strategy ='mean', axis = 0)
imputer =  imputer.fit(Xt[:,3:5])
Xt[:,3:5] = imputer.transform(Xt[:,3:5])

Xt_one = np.array(Xt[:,0:2],dtype = np.float)
ColThreet = Xt[:,2]
Xt_two = np.array(Xt[:,3:6],dtype=np.float)
ColSevent = Xt[:,6]

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
lett = LabelEncoder()
Xt[:,2] = lett.fit_transform(ColThreet)

lest = LabelEncoder()
Xt[:,6] = lest.fit_transform(Xt[:,6])


#This is where the error is thrown
ohct = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[6])
Xt = ohct.fit_transform(Xt).toarray()
```

Thank you for any help you can provide. I realize that my naming convention is weird, but it is because I used basically the same variables I did for my training code, so I added a 't' at the end of each variable to 'reuse' the names for the test set code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your imported modules for reproducible code. And a small data sample.

Answer (score 1):

There are still null values and hence the error message. By quickly running your code I could see there is a null value in 2nd feature.

Just after `Xt = np.concatenate((X_onet,X_twot),axis=1)` I could see there are null values in 2nd and 4th feature

`pd.DataFrame(Xt).isnull().sum()`

while you just pass feature 3:5 for null handling

Just checking before encoding confirms this. Hope this helps.
Just a quick suggestion off topic.You should always include column headers, as it will help getting some intuition about data and results.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the df['columnX'].fillna(0) to your dataframe to use 0 as a default value.